# Force Render in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Widgets like `PreferredSize` or `SliverAppBar.expandedHeight` need an actual height number to work, but sometimes I want that height to be the height of another `Widget` that hasn't been rendered yet, so it's height is unknown.

I would like then to simulate the Flutter Framework itself and falsely render a copy of that widget, so I could grab it's size and them use it on the first time my `build` function runs.

How can this be done?

Comment: Are you looking for https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html

Comment: No `LayoutBuilder` informs the constraints of the layout that our widget has, I want the size without constraints. For example, using `LayoutBuilder` inside an `AppBar.flexibleSpace` we get the `AppBar` height, which is fixed and small. Using it inside a `SliverAppBar` will inform how big the `SliverAppBar` can be, that's not what I want either, I want to know how big is another widget, like an image or dynamic text, so I can put it inside a `SliverAppBar` knowing it's height beforehand, so I can pass it to `expandedHeight`.